# Meraki Switch Uplink

Tags: cisco, switch, meraki

I have a new switch from Cisco Meraki (MS220-8P) and i am trying to configure a Dual Up-link to a 48 port Catalyst 3750 (which is provided by our phone & IS provider). The Catalyst 3750 has been configured to receive the dual up-link but I cannot find where to configure a dual up-link in the Meraki Control Panel.

Comment: What do you mean by a "dual up-link"? If it's going to combine both connections for a higher overall throughput, you might be looking for settings relating to `Port-Channel`, `LACP`, `Etherchannel`, `bonding` or `link aggregation`. But you can connect two cables in an active/standby failover design with `Spanning-Tree`, or two cables, each running different VLANs, which would need `VLAN` configuration on the individual ports.

Comment: thanks. Yeah i want to double the throughput. To be fair i did research i just cant find a lot of information on the meraki switch's ... and older cisco switches use iptables which is way more flexible and i know how to use since is essentially the same as linux servers which is what i deal with most often. Up-link ports are designed to be connected to switches (or master servers) as opposed to "regular" ports which has lower priority in managed switches. Dual refers to two. I found where i can aggregate/bond two regular ports but i still don't no how to assign this to Up-link priortiy

Comment: Doing test i figured it out. The switch will automatically detect and assign the up-link priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link Aggregation is configurable on the Switch Ports (Switch -> Monitor -> Switch Ports) page. From my experience the ports have to be unused when configuring them.

Select two (or up to 8) and the "aggregation" button appears. Click to configure It uses LACP to perform aggregation.

To make this the up-link all you do is connect the up link to these port and it will detect and assign the priority automatically.